# SpriteKit: Texture Atlas won't get loaded on second target

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, target, texture-atlas

I added a second target to my iOS game to craft a lite version. Then I added all common resources to the second target, including texture atlases, by checking the target in "Target Membership" in the File Inspector.

When I launch it, it says stuff like

```
2014-03-01 14:33:13.715 LE Lite[377:60b] SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "LE_Rocketship_Hull.png"
```

Does anyone see what I'm missing here? I already relaunched Xcode and cleaned the build folder with no effect.

Comment: Oh I just remembered... you also have to set the "Enable Texture Atlas Generation" flag under the SpriteKit Deployment Options ;) Will answer this question myself as soon as I can, I'm blocked for another 8 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the "Enable Texture Atlas Generation" flag under the SpriteKit Deployment Options.